# Parameters in console works in the working directory but not outside?

Tags: shell, unix, mono, debian

I've an issue with a script, for example, when I type this command on my remote debian on the directory where the .EXE is : /opt/foo/bar.exe, I make this command `mono bar.exe -nogui`, this works.

But when I'm outside this working directory, the argument `-nogui` for example I'm in the home `mono /opt/foo/bar.exe -nogui` and I've an error, the program won't run (because it uses a GUI).
My question is, how to make it works outside the working directory because I need to make a daemon of it !

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/mono-runtime-common/mono.1.en.html) gives this synopsis:

```
mono [options] file [arguments...]
```

I guess `-nogui` gets taken as an option to mono, not as an argument to your exe.
Have you tried `mono /opt/foo/bar.exe nogui`?

Comment: Same as before...the only workaround I found is to put a cd to the working directory...the script works but I cannot launch it as a daemon in the init.d....